# How can you rewrite "begin" in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

As the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)#Standard_forms) article explains, `begin` in Scheme is a library form that can be rewritten using more fundamental forms like `lambda`.

But how do you rewrite a `begin`, especially considering the following?

```
x
===> error: undefined identifier: x
(begin (define x 28) x)
===> 28
x
===> 28
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot.  The thing is that `begin` has two roles: one is sequence a bunch of side-effectful expressions, and the other is that it is used to "splice" macro results.  The fact that you can use `begin` with a definition as in the above is a result of this second feature, and you cannot write it yourself.

If you really want to follow the whole story, then you *could* define `begin` as the simple macro which makes it do only the sequencing aspect (and it can indeed be implemented as such, though usually it isn't).  *But*, you need to add explicit recognition of `begin`s to splice definitions (toplevel or internal).  This means that a macro implementation is fine, but it cannot really be a library because the core expander should know about it.  (And because the language is lexically scoped, there is no good way for the core expander to identify `begin`s that are not defined in the core language.)

To summarize all of this, you could say that R5RS is only wrong in classifying `begin` as "library syntax", since it can't be defined in a library... but even that's not entirely accurate since R5RS defines "library syntax" as just "derived expressions".  The real wrong point is, therefore, the fact that one of `begin`s two faces is implemented elsewhere, in the expander (for definition contexts).

Note also that R6RS clarifies the whole deal: the two faces of `begin` are made explicit, and it is now part of the core language, not a "library form", and not even a derived form.

Comment: Then why is it considered a"library syntax", and not simply "syntax" in R5RS? I thought you could rewrite library forms using fundamental forms only?

Comment: That's a mistake (together with the wikipedia article).

Comment: No, a citation is not needed -- a counter example is sufficient.  eljenso's example *is* such a counter example.

Comment: Wait a minute, section 7.3 of R5RS defines `begin` as a macro rewritten as `(lambda () exp ...)` - http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_7.3 ... does the counter example imply that the spec is incorrect?

Comment: @JustinEthier: I've expanded the text to make it more accurate.

Comment: @EliBarzilay: What would you say about @grettke's definition?  I have tried it on several different Scheme implementations.  They give different results on `(sequencing (define x 28) x)`.  Racket and Guile reports an error, telling a definition in an expression context disallowed.  While Chicken and Chibi returns `28`.  Also it is a bit confusing to call a hole in a macro call an expression context.  What is the reason behind to disallow definitions in such a context?

Comment: @plmday: I don't know what you did, but it should work on racket too; still, my point is that this is *not* implementing a `begin`.

Comment: @EliBarzilay: I did nothing but copy and paste @grettke's code into the definition area of DrRacket, click the Run button, enter `(sequencing (define x 28) x)` in the interaction area, and get the error (copied as reported): "define: not allowed in an expression context in: (define x 28)".  It just does not work.  If you do not believe, you can try it yourself.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you expected the definition of `sequencing` to work, i.e., , `(begin (define x 28) x) ===> 28`, even under Racket, although it does not.  So does it suggest that there is still part of the second role you mentioned of `begin` that can be separated out if `begin` is defined this way?

Comment: @plmday: Sorry, I haven't actually looked at his definition -- and indeed, it would not work in racket, since your expression expands to: `((lambda (ignored) x) (define x 28))`, using a definition as an expression.  Schemes that allow that to work surprise me, since it can be used to create some very "semantically weird" code.  In any case, it's the first role -- sequencing expressions -- that can be implemented as a macro, the splicing part is what cannot be done.

Comment: By _semantically weird_ code, you mean for example `(+ (define x 28) 2)`?  But in this case, a run-time error can be issued, suppose `define` returns a special value like `<undefined>`.  Or you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, that's the weird code.  Unrelated to a runtime type error -- I consider `(list (define x 1) x)` to be just as weird.  Also, does `(list x (define x 1))` work?  What about `(let ([x 1]) (list x (define x 2) x))` or `(let () (list (define x 1)))`?  (Looks like Chicken's repl is seriously tripping on that last one.)  In any case, this is not a good medium for an actual discussion...

Comment: Here's another bad one: `(let ((x 1)) (list x (define x (+ x 1)) x))`

Answer (score 2):

You are still welcome to try writing a version of begin which satisfies its first role: sequencing.

```
(define-syntax sequencing
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ expression) expression]
    [(_ expression expressions ...)
     ((lambda (ignored) (sequencing expressions ...)) expression)]))
```

Here is the post from which I took that snippet. It provides better context if you are [interested](http://www.wisdomandwonder.com/article/527/sequencing-in-scheme), and you might be.