# shorthand for ((lambda () ))

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, r6rs

Is there a shorthand in scheme for ((lambda () ))

For example, instead of

```
((lambda ()
    (define x 1)
    (display x)))
```

I would love to be able to do something like

```
(empty-lambda
    (define x 1)
    (display x))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual idiom for that is

```
(let ()
  (define x 1)
  (display x))
```

which you can of course turn into a quick macro:

```
(define-syntax-rule (block E ...) (let () E ...))
```

Comment: I thought the obvious answer would be to use `begin`, like: `(begin (define x 1) (display x))` Turns out to be obvious and wrong, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683796/how-can-you-rewrite-begin-in-scheme/1683842#1683842.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```
(let
    ((x 1))
    (display x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Racket provides the [`block`](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/block.html) form, which works like this:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/block)
(block
 (define x 1)
 (display x))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(define-syntax empty-lambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((empty-lambda body ...)
      ((lambda () body ...)))))
```

Comment: Yes I realize that but I wanted something built-in. Thanks though!